# WInForms. Назначить функцию onClick форме

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Dictionary<MyForm, PictureBox[]> gallery = ...;


void getImagesToSecondForm(PictureBox[] pics){
     fp2.Controls.Clear();
     foreach (var pic in pics)
        {
            fp2.Controls.Add(pic);
        }
}

foreach (var item in gallery)
{
   //Как тут назначить?
   item.Key.Click += getImagesToSecondForm(item.Value) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы напишите `item.Key.Click +=` и нажмете `TAB` в Visual Studio, то та вам создаст метод-обработчик, который обязательно должен принимать два значения:

```
private void Key_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Реализация.
}
```

Эти значения обязательны, вы от них не избавитесь. Вот внутри этого метода вы уже и пишете что вам необходимо.

---

Подпись на события также возможна при помощи так называемой "лямбды", она значительно сокращает код и тут не обязательно создавать дополнительный метод. Метод выше можно записать как:

```
item.Key.Click += (s, e) => 
{
    //Реализация.
};
```

Сокращаем еще, дописываем ваш метод и получаем следующее:

```
item.Key.Click += (s, e) => getImagesToSecondForm(item.Value);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Пишет "Локальная переменная или параметр с именем "e" нельзя объявить в данной области, так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра"

Comment: Ну наверно у вас уже есть где то `e`? Название каждой переменной должно быть уникально.